# problem converting json response to object in Flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter

first all sorry about my "engrish"...
I'm trying to consume an own API method with http package in Flutter.
I'm able to get a response from API but I'm having trouble trying to map the response (json) to my custom object called APILoginResponse.

I'm calling the API method like this:

```
APILoginResponse apiLogin = await api.apiLogin();
```

but I'm getting a runtime error "dynamic is not subtype of AccessToken".

Here is my API login method:

```html
Future<APILoginResponse> apiLogin() async {
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    api_end_point + '/api/Auth/login',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(
        <String, String>{'userName': api_user, 'password': api_password}),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return APILoginResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Error en login de la API');
  }
}
```

...and here is my APILoginResponse object:

```html
class APILoginResponse {
  final AccessToken accessToken;
  final String refreshToken;

  APILoginResponse({this.accessToken, this.refreshToken});

  factory APILoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return APILoginResponse(
      accessToken: json['accessToken'],
      refreshToken: json['refreshToken'],
    );
  }
}

class AccessToken {
  String token;
  int expiresIn;
}
```

error is in the line:

```
accessToken: json['accessToken']
```

inside APILoginResponse class.

Here is my json response:

```html
{
  "accessToken": {
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiIiLCJzdWIiOiJib3N0b25jcmVkX2NsaWVudGVzIiwianRpIjoiZjBkMzY0ZDMtMmRkNS00NzkzLWE5ZTktMzY1YzJmODNiYmI3IiwiaWF0IjoxNTk0MTMxODAwLCJyb2wiOiJhcGlfYWNjZXNzIiwiaWQiOiIyMzg3YTMzZi1hYzE5LTRhMzYtODcyZC04MTE3MzExZDFjY2IiLCJuYmYiOjE1OTQxMzE3OTksImV4cCI6MTU5NDEzMjM5OSwiaXNzIjoid2ViQXBpIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzMTcvLyJ9.PqCPkVct4e4duWFEr63fALZ0h_0x25vsV_GBx336Apw",
    "expiresIn": 600
  },
  "refreshToken": "W6wyiw9xYuC2UaJmyCOYujKIZTs0jAscnfcWTrEyVIk="
}
```

Any help with this will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the returning value is an `AccessToken` you can try this:

```
  factory APILoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   return APILoginResponse(
   accessToken: (json['accessToken'] as Map<String,dynamic>) as AccessToken ?? null,
   refreshToken: json['refreshToken'],
   );
 }
```

Change your AccessToken class to this:

```
class AccessToken {
   final Map<String,dynamic> tokenData;
   AccessToken(tokenData)
}
```

Comment: Thanks P4yam, unfortunately I get the same error with your code.

Comment: is that the same error? what does `print(${json['accessToken']})` show?

Comment: {{token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiIiLCJzdWIiOiJib3N0b25jcmVkX2NsaWVudGVzIiwianRpIjoiZjQxNWJlMWEtNTgyZC00ZGY3LTgzOGItNDljYTdkZGJiNGNiIiwiaWF0IjoxNTk0MTQ1MTYwLCJyb2wiOiJhcGlfYWNjZXNzIiwiaWQiOiIyMzg3YTMzZi1hYzE5LTRhMzYtODcyZC04MTE3MzExZDFjY2IiLCJuYmYiOjE1OTQxNDUxNjAsImV4cCI6MTU5NDE0NTc2MCwiaXNzIjoid2ViQXBpIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzMTcvLyJ9.bQLG-31ggBBsrz-7T6n5cIlwiBpaSoHrdfxla4-VaxQ, expiresIn: 600}}

Comment: I edited my original original post and added the json response from API

Comment: the type of `accessToken` is `Map<String,dynamic>`. I edit my answer. see if that works

Comment: same error, it says: _CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'AccessToken' in type cast)

Comment: do you write AccessToken  yourself or is it from a library or something?

Comment: yes I wrote the AcessToken class, it is in my original post, below APILoginResponse class

Comment: oh, your AccessToken class does not have any constructor or something.

Comment: not sure about this, but I will try... why I should change the structure of the class?... tested, same error :S

Comment: You where trying to change a map to two separate strings without doing anything. you can keep the old strings but then you should change the `APILoginResponse.fromJson` method.

Answer (score 0):

well I think @P4yam answer was right but I was getting the same error over and over, so I changed my APILoginResponse class as follow:

```html
class APILoginResponse {
  AccessToken accessToken;
  String refreshToken;

  APILoginResponse({this.accessToken, this.refreshToken});

  APILoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    accessToken = json['accessToken'] != null
        ? new AccessToken.fromJson(json['accessToken'])
        : null;
    refreshToken = json['refreshToken'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.accessToken != null) {
      data['accessToken'] = this.accessToken.toJson();
    }
    data['refreshToken'] = this.refreshToken;
    return data;
  }
}

class AccessToken {
  String token;
  int expiresIn;

  AccessToken({this.token, this.expiresIn});

  AccessToken.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    token = json['token'];
    expiresIn = json['expiresIn'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['token'] = this.token;
    data['expiresIn'] = this.expiresIn;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and everything works fine now! thanks!